# How can I make an ordered list go 1. 1.1, 1.2, A, B, C, 1.3, 1.4

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Since I have not found a post on StackOverflow that satisfies my needs for what I am trying to do, I have made a new question covering my problem.

I am trying to build an ordered list, where I want to have:

```
1.
  1.1
     A
     B
     C
  1.2
  1.3
```

Currently, I have the following:

```
1.
  1.1
     1.1.1
     1.1.2
     1.1.3
  1.2
  1.3
```

I have tried a few things without luck though, so I would appreciate if I can get some help.

Is this possible what I am trying to do? If yes, how? If no, why?

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: table;
    counter-increment: item;
    margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li li {
    margin: 10px;
}

li li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}


.bolder {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin: 0px;
}

.parent::before {
    font-size: 1.17em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<li class="parent">
  <p class="bolder">How I want it to look like</p>
  <ol>
    <li>This is 1.1
      <ol>
        <li class="subItem">
          This is what I want to be A
        </li>
        <li class="subItem">
          This is what I want to be B
        </li>
        <li class="subItem">
          This is what I want to be C
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      Then it continues on with 1.2
    </li>
    <li>
      Then 1.3.. etc.
    </li>
  </ol>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target the third level of `li`s you can use the `ol ol ol li` selector. To use uppercase letters, you can use a [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter()) instead of [`counters()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counters()) as with `counters()` the generated text is the value of all counters while with `counter()` it's the value of the innermost counter only.

If you set the counter style to `upper-alpha` the markers will be uppercase letters.

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: table;
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}

li li {
  margin: 10px;
}

li li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

.bolder {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0px;
}

.parent::before {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

ol ol ol li:before {
  content: counter(item, upper-alpha);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="parent">
    <p class="bolder">How I want it to look like</p>
    <ol>
      <li>This is 1.1
        <ol>
          <li class="subItem">
            This is what I want to be A
          </li>
          <li class="subItem">
            This is what I want to be B
          </li>
          <li class="subItem">
            This is what I want to be C
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Then it continues on with 1.2
      </li>
      <li>
        Then 1.3.. etc.
        <ol>
          <li class="subItem">
            This is what I want to be A
          </li>
          <li class="subItem">
            This is what I want to be B
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help! That is exactly what I wanted :D

Can it also be made such that it display (a) instead of A? (for a learning standpoint)

Comment: You can swap `upper-alpha` with `lower-alpha` to use lowercase letters. You will find [all available options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type#values) on MDN.

Comment: Thanks that is done now ;) 

Thanks a lot for the help.

Have a happy new  year!

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to approach this would be to assign a class to the list that you want to display the letter style then use list-style-type:upper-alpha in that class.

Comment: OP is styling the `::before` pseudo-element, so `list-style-type` won't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).